# "hope someone/something would..." - When to use it?

Tags: grammar, tense, verbs

Typically, people use the present tense, the future tense ("will"), or the present continuous ("be doing") in the clause following the verb "hope" in the present tense. ([Reference here.](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1837_aae/page4.shtml)) However a few examples use "would" in the clause instead:

> *I hope people would* say in 20 years that Gwinnett County is a place where parents are interested and involved in the education of their children .

> *I hope things would* not get that far.

> This is his first book of poetry and *he hopes it would* perhaps influence and help others.

> Whatever the editor replies, *one hopes it would* be in the form of a good rejoinder that one can later use for amusement.

(All above examples from [Linggle](https://linggle.com/).)

When is the use of "would" following "hope" in the present tense correct? How is the meaning different from a verb in the present or future tense?

Answer (score 0):

Your last sentence is actually in the future tense, so you would use "hope it would". "Would hope"/"hope something would" usually *already* denotes a future present.

Comment: Where does the "would hope" you mention refer to? None of the examples uses the "would hope" structure.

Comment: @tvk I have edited my answer